# Incorrect visualization of c3.js graph

Tags: javascript, reactjs, c3.js

I am trying to draw a very basic line chart using c3.js in react. But the the chart output appears with dark areas around the lines, which I assume is not a feature of the graph, because I used another graph library and the dark areas persisted. Anyone knows what the source of error can be?

Here is a picture of how the chart looks like:
[image]

Here is the code:

```
import React from "react";
import * as c3  from 'c3'
class Hello extends React.Component {
drawGraph = () =>
{
    var chart = c3.generate({
        bindto: this.refs.chart,
        data: {
            xs: {
                'data1': 'x1',
                'data2': 'x2',
            },
            columns: [
                ['x1', 10, 30, 45, 50, 70, 100],
                ['x2', 30, 50, 75, 100, 120],
                ['data1', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250],
                ['data2', 20, 180, 240, 100, 190]
            ]
        }
    });
}
render() {
return (
    <div>
        <br/>
        <div id='chart' ref={'chart'} style={{width: '100%', height: '100%'}}><button onClick={this.drawGraph}>draw</button></div>
    </div>
          );
 }
 }

export default Hello;
```

Answer (score 1):

If the package was installed using npm (i.e. `npm install c3` or `yarn add c3`), it's necessary import the styles from .css files: Inside the main component, add the line

```js
import "c3/c3.min.css";
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the problem can be solved just by adding a single line of code in the beginning:

```
import "../../node_modules/c3/c3.css";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you come across here as I did from top results of google search, you will be probably surprised why both of other solutions don't work.

In **Vue 3 Cli** there is issue with `.css` file loader not working properly, but you can circumvent this if you add to your `main.js` file, following line:

```
require('c3/c3.css');// C3 chart styles
```

This will enable you to use c3 in rest of your project, with importing c3 in components like so:

```
<template> 
    <div id="testChart"></div> 
</template>
<script>
    var c3 = require('c3');    
    export default {
        async mounted() {
            c3.generate({
                bindto: "#testChart",
                data: {
                columns: [
                    ['data1', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250],
                    ['data2', 50, 20, 10, 40, 15, 25]
                ]
                }
            });
        }
    };
</script>
```